# Manipulate time-range in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date-range

Need to clean up a csv import, which gives me a range of times (in string form). Code is at bottom; I currently use regular expressions and `replace()` on the df to convert other chars. Just not sure how to:

1. select the current 24 hour format numbers and add :00
2. how to select the 12 hour format numbers and make them 24 hour.

Input (from csv import):

```
   break_notes
0        15-18
1  18.30-19.00
2      4PM-5PM
3          3-4
4     4-4.10PM
5      15 - 17
6      11 - 13
```

So far I have got it to look like (remove spaces, AM/PM, replace dot with colon):

```
   break_notes
0          15-18
1    18:30-19:00
2            4-5
3            3-4
4         4-4:10
5          15-17
6          11-13
```

However, I would like it to look like this ('HH:MM-HH:MM' format):

```
   break_notes
0    15:00-18:00
1    18:30-19:00
2    16:00-17:00
3    15:00-16:00
4    16:00-16:10
5    15:00-17:00
6    11:00-13:00
```

My code is:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
data.break_notes = data.break_notes.str.replace(r'([P].|[ ])', '').str.strip()
data.break_notes = data.break_notes.str.replace(r'([.])', ':').str.strip()
```

Comment: Please state your question in words, don't just show data and say "my input looks like this" and "I want it to look like this".

Comment: Just not sure how to 1 select the current 24 hour format numbers and add :00. Secondly how to select the 12 hour format numbers and make them 24 hour. Not sure how to go about this. Any help would be great.

Comment: pandas has [`between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) for exactly this purpose: representing a range of times, and it supports comparison (which your string doesn't). Do you want that instead of a string? Also, you can use [`pd.read_csv(..., converters)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to convert custom date/time formats (if they're in a single column); `between_time()` will need a date to attach to (today? specific date? range of dates?)

Comment: I have a timesheet for time start and end that is in 24-hour format. The break notes table that comes in is always a mix of all sorts of times. I then use the formated break notes to get the total time between start and end by removing break time.

Comment: @Saritus answer is good but it's going into the trope of using a **for loop** would there be a way to use his method on a data frame and keep it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the converter function that you need based on your requested input data. `convert_entry` takes complete value entry, splits it on a dash, and passes its result to `convert_single`, since both halfs of one entry can be converted individually. After each conversion, it merges them with a dash.

`convert_single` uses regex to search for important parts in the time string.
It starts with a some numbers `\d+` (representing the hours), then optionally a dot or a colon and some more number `[.:]?(\d+)?` (representing the minutes). And after that optionally AM or PM `(AM|PM)?` (only PM is relevant in this case)

```
import re


def convert_single(s):
    m = re.search(pattern="(\d+)[.:]?(\d+)?(AM|PM)?", string=s)
    hours = m.group(1)
    minutes = m.group(2) or "00"
    if m.group(3) == "PM":
        hours = str(int(hours) + 12)
    return hours.zfill(2) + ":" + minutes.zfill(2)


def convert_entry(value):
    start, end = value.split("-")
    start = convert_single(start)
    end = convert_single(end)
    return "-".join((start, end))


values = ["15-18", "18.30-19.00", "4PM-5PM", "3-4", "4-4.10PM", "15 - 17", "11 - 13"]

for value in values:
    cvalue = convert_entry(value)
    print(cvalue)
```